# PHP Commercial round currency

Tags: php, rounding, currency

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I would like to know what sollutions you can come up with for the following problem:

This is what I have:

```
13.90
5.03
7.06
2.51
```

This is what I want:

```
13.90
5.05
7.05
2.50
```

Basically: I want to round currency on a commercial base. There last decimal may only be rounded up to 5 or 10 (adding one to the first digit) or rounded down to 5 or 0.

Comment: comparing 5.03 with 5.05 and 2.51 with 2.50, which rule should taken for the round up/down decision?

Comment: Your rounding algorithm is inconsistent. if 03 rounds to 05, and 51 rounds to 50, than 06 should round to 05, not 10. if 06 round to 10, 03 should round to 00.

Comment: Thank you for noticing! I errored that!

Comment: @Daxcode The rule is that the number must be rounded to the nearest .05 digit. This way the last digit can only be a 5 or a 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A general formula for rounding to the nearest `x`:

```
round(input / x) * x
```

And an example for your use case:

```
round(5.03 / .05) * .05 = round(100.6) * .05 = 101 * .05 = 5.05
```

Comment: Using `round(input / x) * x` will work with the OP's numbers because they are simple enough: they have few decimal digits and `input / x` cannot be a midpoint in his case. But note that if `input` and `x` are expressed in decimal, there will be rounding errors for the internal conversion to binary and for the division. So, in more complex cases, the formula may fail in floating-point arithmetic. Possible solutions: integer arithmetic or error analysis & midpoint detection.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

$int = 5.03;
$int *= 20;
$int = ceil($int);
$int /= 20;

echo $int;
```

You just need to define the resolution of the rounding by multiplying the number (and later on dividing it again). It's a simple math problem.